# Preservatives in food = preservatives in my fat cells?

Tags: weight-loss, nutrition, body-fat, fat, nutrition-information

Is it logical to believe that if I eat foods with preservatives, the resulting fats within that food may also store within my fat cells with preservatives and thus make it more difficult to rid my body of those fat cells?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no logic behind that belief. Historically speaking, some preservatives have since been proven to have potential negative effects. We no longer pack our meat in cakes of salt. We know that burning the outside of the meat preserves it, but also produces carcinogens. And, of course, we now know that packaging our food inside lead containers has certain negative effects. That said, [modern preservatives are consistently safe](http://www.eufic.org/page/en/page/FAQ/faqid/preservatives-harmful-eat-regularly/) and the mechanics that make food preservatives work (retardation of bacteria and fungal growth) have nothing to do with the process of ["burning" fat](http://www.active.com/fitness/articles/how-does-your-body-burn-fat).